# How to know if a docker container is running in privileged mode

Tags: bash, shell, docker, containers, dockerfile

Would like to know via bash script, if current running container was started in `--privileged` mode from **inside** the container (not from the host machine).

For now I'm stuck with passing an env var with the flag but is not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

### From the docker host

Use the [docker inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) command:

```
docker inspect --format='{{.HostConfig.Privileged}}' <container id>
```

And within a bash script you could have a test:

```bash
if [[ $(docker inspect --format='{{.HostConfig.Privileged}}' <container id>) == "false" ]]; then
    echo not privileged
else
    echo privileged
fi
```

### From inside the container itself

You have to try to run a command that requires the [`--privileged`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) flag and see if it fails

For instance `ip link add dummy0 type dummy` is a command which requires the `--privileged` flag to be successful:

```
$ docker run --rm -it ubuntu ip link add dummy0 type dummy
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

while

```
$ docker run --rm -it --privileged ubuntu ip link add dummy0 type dummy
```

runs fine.

In a bash script you could do something similar to this:

```bash
ip link add dummy0 type dummy >/dev/null
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    PRIVILEGED=true
    # clean the dummy0 link
    ip link delete dummy0 >/dev/null
else
    PRIVILEGED=false
fi
```

Comment: I am trying to make a container privileged and also add caps with `docker_container` from Ansible, but no success, no error message but at the end the container is not running on privileged  mode at all. Anyone with a fix for this?

Comment: [docker inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) url has changed

Comment: with crictl ? this does not work

Answer (score -6):

From inside the container, your docker commands (`docker ps` or `docker inspect` or any) will be available if your `docker run` command has `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: True but overkill IMHO. That also gives the container full access to the host machine.

Comment: how is linking the docker socket to the container giving full access to host? There are a lot of people linking the docker executable from the host.

Comment: The docker commands are not available unless you install docker inside the container or use the API in weird ways.  And, true, it would be overkill.  A compromised container could create havoc.

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea Access to the Docker daemon allows you to run arbitrary commands in arbitrarily configured containers. One exploit is that, since you can mount any file or directory on the host into the container, you can modify any file on the host. Here's an example of [leveraging Docker for root access](https://github.com/0cjs/sedoc/blob/master/app/docker.md#leveraging-docker-for-root-access) on the host. (Somehow blocking this particular avenue still leaves many other exploits open.)

Comment: Bad security practice indeed, should be avoided unless absolutely necessary, and isolated if possible (dedicated node in k8s for example, with dedicated PSP/useraccount). @cjs +1